# Xcode 13.0 - No matching function for call to 'RCTBridgeModuleNameForClass'

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

After updating Xcode to 13.0, my React Native app does not build, throwing this error:

`No matching function for call to 'RCTBridgeModuleNameForClass'`

Already added this fix from Xcode 12.5 to fix this issue, but it is not working for Xcode 13.0

```
post_install do |installer|
    
    flipper_post_install(installer)
    
    ## Fix for XCode 12.5
    find_and_replace("../node_modules/react-native/React/CxxBridge/RCTCxxBridge.mm",
    "_initializeModules:(NSArray<id<RCTBridgeModule>> *)modules", "_initializeModules:(NSArray<Class> *)modules")
    find_and_replace("../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/turbomodule/core/platform/ios/RCTTurboModuleManager.mm",
    "RCTBridgeModuleNameForClass(module))", "RCTBridgeModuleNameForClass(Class(module)))")
    
    def find_and_replace(dir, findstr, replacestr)
      Dir[dir].each do |name|
          text = File.read(name)
          replace = text.gsub(findstr,replacestr)
          if text != replace
              puts "Fix: " + name
              File.open(name, "w") { |file| file.puts replace }
              STDOUT.flush
          end
      end
      Dir[dir + '*/'].each(&method(:find_and_replace))
    end
  end
```